# C# - Encode video with Azure Media Services asynchronously and handle task complete

Tags: c#, asynchronous, azure-media-services

I have an ASP.NET MVC web application and I want to encode a video using Azure Media Services.

Since this process lasts too long, I need to **run it asynchronously** so I don't keep the user waiting for this action to be processed. Also, I need to somehow **handle the execution of this task, as soon as it ends**.

**Azure Media Services documentation** provides a code skeleton for implementing this:

```
static public IAsset EncodeToAdaptiveBitrateMP4Set(IAsset asset)
{
    // Declare a new job.
    IJob job = _context.Jobs.Create("Media Encoder Standard Job");
    // Get a media processor reference, and pass to it the name of the 
    // processor to use for the specific task.
    IMediaProcessor processor = GetLatestMediaProcessorByName("Media Encoder Standard");

    // Create a task with the encoding details, using a string preset.
    // In this case "Adaptive Streaming" preset is used.
    ITask task = job.Tasks.AddNew("My encoding task",
        processor,
        "Adaptive Streaming",
        TaskOptions.None);

    // Specify the input asset to be encoded.
    task.InputAssets.Add(asset);
    // Add an output asset to contain the results of the job. 
    // This output is specified as AssetCreationOptions.None, which 
    // means the output asset is not encrypted. 
    task.OutputAssets.AddNew("Output asset",
        AssetCreationOptions.None);

    job.StateChanged += new EventHandler<JobStateChangedEventArgs>(JobStateChanged);
    job.Submit();
    job.GetExecutionProgressTask(CancellationToken.None).Wait();

    return job.OutputMediaAssets[0];
}

private static void JobStateChanged(object sender, JobStateChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // do something when job state changes 
}
```

This code does the job of encoding the video in Azure Media Services, but the processing is done synchronously, so the user is blocked until this action ends.

Instead of this instruction that makes the program wait for the task to end:

```
job.GetExecutionProgressTask(CancellationToken.None).Wait();
```

, I need something to make the job run async in Azure Media Services, and to be able to handle the end of the task (run a certain code when the encoding ends).

Can you help me with this? If you need more info, please give a shout!

Comment: `Task.ContinueWith` is a starting point. You'll have to hang onto a reference to the task somewhere so that it doesn't get collected (I dunno, that's a bit of cargo culting, but I'd wager it'd work). You'd have to use something like Signalr or polling from the browser to update the user when it's done.

Answer (score 0):

We'd recommend that you register for notifications - see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/media-services-dotnet-check-job-progress-with-webhooks) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

What about just:

```
await job.GetExecutionProgressTask(CancellationToken.None);
```